# BrowserWindow doesn’t open an https page without ignore-certificate-errors

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, electron

I'm working on a very simple Electron application to load up a secure website which asks for a certificate for login.

```
var url = "https://...";
mainWindow.loadURL(url);
```

However, the application window is blank unless I use the **ignore-certificate-errors** command line switch for Chromium, which undoubtedly makes it unsafe.

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch("ignore-certificate-errors");
```

When I use the *network* tab in the Dev tools, I can see that the website is loaded after the certificate is chosen (but there is no SSL with the regular http), but it just doesn't work with the https version of the page. 
Is there a way to see why it doesn't do anything without the switch?

Comment: If you have to add this switch, it means that your target _secure_ website has an error in its certificate. Can you check that point by opening directly the URL ?

Comment: @lansus The website can be successfully opened in standalone browsers and the certificate is accepted.

Comment: Is there some error log provided in the Javascript console ? E.g. with Firefox, open it with F12 and try to manually execute your loadURL code. Maybe the cert error will display there